# Tensorflow 2.0: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'is_floating' when using GradientTape to explicitly calculate and apply gradient

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, tensorflow2.0

For reinforcement learning I would like to explicitly

- compute the neural network gradient with respect to output softmax probabilities
- update the neural network weights by gradients * advantage score of actions. (increase probability of successful actions, decrease probability of unsuccessful actions)

I created an agent with a simple policy network:

```
def simple_policy_model(self):        
    inputs = Input(shape=(self.state_size,), name="Input")
    outputs = Dense(self.action_size, activation='softmax', name="Output")(inputs)
    predict_model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    return predict_model
```

Then I try to get gradients:

```
agent = REINFORCE_Agent(state_size=env.observation_space.shape[0],
                        action_size=env.action_space.n)
print(agent.predict_model.summary())
state_memory = np.random.uniform(size=(3,4))/10
#state_memory = tf.convert_to_tensor(state_memory)
print(state_memory)
print(agent.predict_model.predict(state_memory))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    probs = agent.predict_model.predict(state_memory)
    ### fails below ###
    grads = tape.gradient(probs, agent.predict_model.trainable_weights)
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Input (InputLayer)           (None, 4)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
Output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 10        
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
state_memory [[0.01130021 0.01476066 0.09524527 0.05552276]
 [0.02018996 0.03127809 0.07232339 0.07146596]
 [0.08925738 0.08890574 0.04845396 0.0056015 ]]
prediction [[0.5127161  0.4872839 ]
 [0.5063317  0.49366832]
 [0.4817074  0.51829267]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'is_floating'
```

If I convert state_memory to tensor by uncommenting convert_to_tensor it fails at .predict():

```
ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data).
```

Seems simple enough but got pretty stuck, any idea what the correct way to obtain the gradients is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that,

`probs = agent.predict_model.predict(state_memory)`

Produces a numpy tensor as the output. And you cannot get gradients `w.r.t` numpy tensors. Instead you need a `tf.Tensor` from your model. For that, do the following.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    probs = agent.predict_model(state_memory)
    ### fails below ###
grads = tape.gradient(probs, agent.predict_model.trainable_weights)
```